# Kivy : Object generating/painting a trail behind while moving

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Good morning / Good evening :-)

I was following a video to try to generate a "trail" from the circle while moving, the trail is the yellow line. Better show an image than a long explanation :
***[> Link to the image on top of the video to describe what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8wuj.png)***
***[> Link to the tutorial video (without trail)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xcrcA3MpJs)***

#### - Could somebody help me to get rid of the error ?

#### - I don't really get how to generate the trail...

...Maybe by painting dots like the painting app but the "on_touch_move" should be like on_move maybe..? 
(I'll post a piece of code at the end)

## The error :

```python
/ex38.kv", line 24:
    ...
         22:    pos: 300,root.top-100
         23:    text:
    >>   24:        ( '[size=32][color=88FF22]' +
         25:        root.ball.anim_choice +
         26:        '[/color][/size]' )
    ...

/ex38.kv", line 24:
    ...
         22:    pos: 300,root.top-100
         23:    text:
    >>   24:        ( '[size=32][color=88FF22]' +
         25:        root.ball.anim_choice +
         26:        '[/color][/size]' )
    ...
    AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'ball'
```

## Main Python :

```python
#ex38.py    
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('ex38.kv')

class Ball(Widget):
    anim_choice = StringProperty('touch_down to animate ball')
    counter = 0
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        Animation.cancel_all(self)
        anim_choices = ['in_back','in_bounce','in_circ',
                        'in_cubic','in_elastic','in_expo',
                        'in_out_back','in_out_bounc','in_out_circ',
                        'out_sine']
        self.anim_choice = anim_choices [self.counter]
        anim = Animation(center_x = touch.x,
                         center_y = touch.y,
                         t = self.anim_choice)
        anim.start(self)
        self.counter = (self.counter+1) % len(anim_choices)

class Ex38(Widget):
   pass

class Ex38App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Ex38()

if  __name__=='__main__':
     Ex38App().run()
```

## Kivy :

```
# ex38.kv

<Ball>:
    size: 65,60
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0.75,0,0
            Ellipse:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

<Ex38>:
    ball: ball_id
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width,root.height
            pos: 0,0

Label:
    pos: 300,root.top-100
    text:
        ( '[size=32][color=88FF22]' +
        root.ball.anim_choice +
        '[/color][/size]' )
    markup: True 
<Ball>:
    id: ball_id
```

**PS** : Ideas for the trail generator :

> Important : 
> - The trail shouldn't be for the mouse movements but related to the Ellipse movements.
>   
> - The circle will not be always moving straight making lines, could also do random trajectories.
>   
>  Generating dots should be ok then...

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch): #That one shouldn't be for the mouse but related to our Ellipse
        global length,n_points,last_x,last_y
        if touch.button=='left':
            touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
            x = int(touch.x)
            y = int(touch.y)
            length += np.sqrt(max((x - last_x)**2 + (y - last_y)**2, 2))
            n_points += 1.
            density = n_points/(length)
            touch.ud['line'].width = int(20*density + 1)
            sand[int(touch.x) - 10 : int(touch.x) + 10, int(touch.y) - 10 : int(touch.y) + 10] = 1
            last_x = x
            last_y = y
```

Best regards, hope you'll be interested.